# Why is my Switch track color white when it's off?

Tags: android, material-design

This is my checked switch:

[image]

And this is my unchecked switch:

[image]

I expect it to be like this:

[image]

**activity_directories.xml**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:checked="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_directories_enable_label"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

**colors.xml**

```
<color name="primaryColor">#ee0000</color>
<color name="primaryLightColor">#ff5f52</color>
<color name="primaryDarkColor">#d90101</color>
<color name="primaryTextColor">#ffffff</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#d90000</color>


<color name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/primaryLightColor</color>

<color name="textColorPrimary">#ffffff</color>
<color name="textColorDark">#333333</color>
<color name="textColorLight">#777777</color>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I tried to replace all the white colors on my **colors.xml** and **styles.xml**, but it didn't work. What I missed?